# jQuery append functions is appending div without css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I try to make an information feed with jQuerys append function. My issue is that I'm creating a div much later than the initial setup of the website this causes that the css style for my div isn't loaded.

I tried to find a solution and saw a lot of people having the same issue and fixing it with an .trigger('create') call on an parent element. But it doesn't work. Here is my function creating and appending the div.

```
function createCriteriaListItem(name) {
            var listItemImage = "<div class='listItemRoundElement listItemImage'> </div>"
            var listItemOuterImage = "<div class='listItem listItemOuter'>" + listItemImage + "</div>"

            //List Item Name
            var listItemName =  "<div class='listItemName'>" + name + "</div>"
            var lisItemInnerName = "<div class='listItem listItemInner'>" + listItemName + "</div>"

            //List Item Select Button
            var listItemSelectButtonAdd = "<div class='addHoriontal'> </div> <div class='addVertical'> </div>"
            var listItemSelectButton = "<div class='listItemRoundElement listItemSelectButton'>" + listItemSelectButtonAdd + "</div>"
            var listItemOuterSelectButton =  "<div class='listItem listItemOuter'>" + listItemSelectButton + "</div>"

            //List Item 
            var informationCriteriaListItemContent = listItemOuterImage + lisItemInnerName + listItemOuterSelectButton
            var informationCriteriaListItem = "<div id=" + name + " class='informationCriteriaListItem'>" + informationCriteriaListItemContent + " </div>"

            $("#informationCriteriaList").append(informationCriteriaListItem).trigger('create');
    }
```

Comment: There isn't any event called `create` unless you use some `plugins`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Do you mean with **plugins** **jQuery** and **jQuery Mobile**?

Comment: i think your javascript is failing, you do not have semi-colons, check your console for errors

Comment: Can you include a live snippet or use JSfiddle to do so.

Comment: Yes.. `jquery Mobile` might have, not sure though! But can you see any `console errors` because as per my knowledge, CSS shouldn't get effected for dynamically added elements!

Comment: I do not have any console errors. Im creating a JSfiddle wait a second

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri Here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa6ce25h/)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the JSFiddle you provided and inspecting the elements, the CSS *IS* in fact loaded. 
The only thing you need to do in your CSS to make *inner* children nodes get affected is to add a `height` property to the `informationCriteriaListItem` class.

```
.informationCriteriaListItem
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 24px;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

Meanwhile, you haven't added the `listItemImage` class on any of the rows.

I suppose you wanted an *alternate* row background style. If so, you can add this to your CSS by specifying *`:nth-child()`* with `even` or `odd` filters:

```
.informationCriteriaListItem:nth-child(even){
     background-color: rgba(71, 126, 209, 0.1);
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/ftbkc1br)

***Note:*** You can omit `.trigger('create')` as it has no effect whatsoever, since `create` is neither a built-in JS event, nor a custom one defined by you.